# Plotting two functions against each other

Tags: plotting

I have two functions which are functions of `t`.  Let's just say `x1[t]` and `x2[t]`.  I want to plot `x1` vs `x2`.  How do I do this?

Comment: I would not delete this just because it's simple.  It's another Google entry point.  I can imagine beginners googling precisely for the title of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-plot-2d-plot-against-two-functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html) will do this.  You can see several examples on its documentation page.

```
ParametricPlot[{x1[t], x2[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Really simple.  Thanks